# How to pass multiple values like 'param1','param2','param3'...for N number to a stored procedure in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

For the parameter `wellid`, I have to pass `'well1','well2','well3'....`

```
create or replace procedure  aoi(
wellid text,
INOUT cumoil numeric,INOUT cumgas numeric) 

AS $BODY$

begin

SELECT SUM(cast(a.oil as decimal)) as cumoil,
SUM(cast(a.gas as decimal)) as cumgas

into cumoil,cumgas

from XYZ a   where "Well ID" in (wellid)
GROUP BY a."Well ID";

commit;
end;$BODY$;
```

Comment: Consider passing the wellids as an array of text and apply the ANY operator instead of IN in the select clause.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

- for the parameter, use data type `text[]`
- pass the array as `'{value1,value2,value3}'`
- compare with `"Well ID"  = ANY (wellid)`

Comment: Hi Laurenz Albe.Thanks for the answer.I have got the final value by using this.Since i used group by ,i got for one wellid value only.After taking selection from all the wells,i got the answer.